# Calling a method on an instance of a class, from another class (or file)

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have a class, named `Family Members` , (in the file `family_members.rb`) which contains attributes such as `name`, `sex`, `type`, `role`, and `age`

Within this class I have defined a method called `parent?` which checks whether an instance of the `Family members` class is of `type` `parent`

The code works fine, but I am wondering would it be possible to define the `parent?` method in another class (perhaps a `superclass` or just have the ability to include the class), as this would make the code neater.

The code that works (but I want to improve):

```
#family_members.rb  

class FamilyMembers

      attr_accessor :name, :sex, :status, :age
      def initialize (name, sex, type, role, age)
        @name = name
        @sex = sex
        @type = type
        @role = role
        @age = age
      end

      # Would Like the ability to put this method in another file or class
      def parent?
        parent_or_child = @type
        role = @role
        age = @age
        name = @name

        if parent_or_child == 'Parent'
        then puts "Yes, this family member is a parent; more specifically, a #{role} named #{name} who is #{age} years old."
        else puts  "This family member is not a parent, it`s only a child; more specifically, a #{role} named #{name} who is #{age} years old."
        end
      end

    end

    fm1 = FamilyMembers.new('John','Male', 'Child', "Son" , "27" )
    fm2 = FamilyMembers.new("Bill","Male", "Parent", "Father" , "63" )

    fm1.parent?
```

I have tried to define the method in another file, called `ParentOrChild.rb`, and include it at the top of `family_members.rb` using `require_relative`. However when I do this, the error message tells me that it cannot load such file..

```
#ParentOrChild.rb

def parent?
  parent_or_child = @type
  role = @role
  age = @age
  name = @name

  if parent_or_child == 'Parent'
  then puts "Yes, this family member is a parent; more specifically, a #{role} named #{name} who is #{age} years old."
  else puts  "This family member is not a parent, it`s only a child; more specifically, a #{role} named #{name} who is #{age} years old."
  end
end
```

I have also tried to define the method in another class (in the file `parent_or_child.rb`:

```
#parent_or_child.rb

class ParentOrChild
  def parent?
    parent_or_child = @type
    role = @role
    age = @age
    name = @name

    if parent_or_child == 'Parent'
    then puts "Yes, this family member is a parent; more specifically, a #{role} named #{name} who is #{age} years old."
    else puts  "This family member is not a parent, it`s only a child; more specifically, a #{role} named #{name} who is #{age} years old."
    end
  end
end
```

However when I do the above, the error tells me that there is an undefined method `parent?` (referring to the `family_members.rb` file.

I am using Ruby 2.0, so I believe it is correct to use `require_relative` rather than `require`.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be great - Thanks.

Comment: You say "the error tells me that there is an undefined method `parent`" but isn't your method named `parent?` such that you would need to call it with `fm1.parent?`

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault, error tells me undefined `parent?` .. will edit question

Comment: Generally speaking, a method ending in a question mark should only return true or false.  Regardless, I do not get an error when I run your code.  I get the expected output.

Comment: The first block of code works fine for me too; but if I delete the `parent?` method within the `FamilyMembers` class and try and call the method from another file it fails (as outlined in the last two code blocks provided)

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into inheritance (or subclasses).  Basically: `class ParentOrChild < FamilyMembers`.  That way the subclass ParentOrChild will inherit the methods of the parent class FamilyMembers.

Comment: Thanks tigeravatar, this works (I wonder is it good practice though?), Should I answer my own question or let you (to get reputation?).

Comment: I have added an answer if you would like to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was originally a comment but it was also the solution, so I am adding it as an answer.

It sounds like you need to look into inheritance (or subclasses). Basically:

```
class ParentOrChild < FamilyMembers
```

That way the subclass ParentOrChild will inherit the methods of the parent class FamilyMembers

As a side note, a method ending in a question mark should only return true or false.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider alternating the programme slightly, since you say `parent?` should return only true or false